# Reading console stream continually in c#

Tags: c#, process

I want to read a continues output stream of cmd in c#. I know that I can redirect the standard output stream and read it. Following is the code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pi= new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(ProgramPATH,Params);
        pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pi.UseShellExecute = false;
        pi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc= new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = pi;
        proc.Start();

        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But this gives the whole output at once. What if I issue `ping` command with `-t` argument? How I can read this stream continually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're calling `ReadToEnd` which will obviously block until the process terminates. You can repeatedly call `Read` or `ReadLine` instead. However, you should consider *either* doing this in a different thread *or* using events such as [`OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) to do this. (If you're using events, you need to call [`BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) to enable the events - see the MSDN examples for details.)

The reason for potentially reading on a different thread is that if you need to read from *both* standard error and standard output, you need to make sure the process doesn't fill up its buffer - otherwise it could block when writing, effectively leading to deadlock. Using the asynchronous approach makes it simpler to handle this.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit on how events could be used in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul: Have you read the documentation I linked to? There are examples there which should help you a lot. If there's some specific aspect which is causing confusion, please say exactly what.

Comment: Awesome info. Thanks! I was wondering what you had in mind, event-wise, and hadn't considered the Process class' events.

Answer (score 2):

To save time for those who don't want to look at the docs, see the last 2 lines in StartProcess and the HandleExeOutput method:

```
void StartProcess()
{
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pi= new 
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(ProgramPATH,Params);
  pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  pi.UseShellExecute = false;
  pi.CreateNoWindow = true;

  System.Diagnostics.Process proc= new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  proc.StartInfo = pi;
  proc.Start();

  proc.OutputDataReceived += HandleExeOutput;
  proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

private void HandleExeOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string output = e.Data;
    // do something here with the string output
}
```